# Should task based interfaces be implemented all-the-way or partially where it makes sense?

Tags: gui-design

We are considering implementing task based interface for our new application. What we are not sure about is should we stick to it consistently for all of our screens or should we leave CRUD screens at some places?

I know I am asking an abstract question but that is actually on purpose; to get an idea about task based interfaces aims and best practices. Are they something one should try to enforce everywhere (if decided to go with it) or "where appropriate"?

Comment: This is a very broad abstract question... the answer could depend on the case. Do you have an example?

Comment: I think it could be mixed depending on your scenario. Consider a warehouse inventory system with user A and user B. User A might be in charge of quickly updating some values (task-oriented), while user B might be be a a super-admin in charge of the entire product library (CRUD might be better here). Not sure if that makes sense. Maybe user B requires specialized features to help manage the sheer amount of products (task-oriented).

Comment: @NicolasHung that's a very good example. Maybe you could put it in a form of an answer so i could ask additional questions there because it nails some of my dilemmas very precisely. tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could be mixed depending on your scenario. Consider a warehouse inventory system with user A and user B. User A might be in charge of quickly updating some values (task-oriented), while user B might be be a a super-admin in charge of the entire product library (CRUD might be better here). Not sure if that makes sense. Maybe user B requires specialized features to help manage the sheer amount of products (task-oriented).

Comment: so, lets say like this... since this is not some form-editing app and although there are different roles, all of them do have some special, partial things to do. there is practically no case for creating/updating whole entities (they are imported initially without users interaction). still, CRUD could also be form with 5 fields 2 of which are read only and 3 of which are editable. so i guess question is also: should we always strive for task based interface whenever possible or should we consider it fully free choice without any special bias to it?

Comment: maybe rephrased: if we decide to go with task based UI - should we at least try to have it everywhere or go for it just where its completely obvious its a good choice? are there any general "guidelines" like that?

Comment: There is prob not a universal answer to this. What matters is what the user performs the best at balanced with your dev budget. I would say test it with your users, or talk to them at a minimum, show them all versions and ask them to perform a few of the usual tasks.